# Android: Finding the App name using http host, Top Level Domain and User Agent

Tags: java, android, http, url, hostname

I am working on a project that aims to find out the application name that made a query from Android based phones. For each query, I have data of http host, Top Level Domain(TLD) and User Agent of the following from:

```
httphost                            TLD                    User Agent
api.geo.kontagent.net            kontagent.net            android-async-http/1.3.1 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)
mobile.aws.weather.com           weather.com              Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.1; SCH-I545 Build/LRX22C)
cm.utag.ksmobile.com             ksmobile.com             Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H)
```

Now using this information, how can I possibly find out the application that was used to make this queries? I know for queries made from Apple devices, there is API in iTunes to find this out but I am not sure how to do this for Android based systems. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This is going to be tricky. Unlike iOS, I do not think that Android centralizes all third party api requests through its own servers. ChromeCast does this, but I do not think that Android does. Are you doing this from an Android device that you physically possess? or an Android device that your app is installed on?

Comment: I am doing it for a data science project. I basically have the data of each query with httphost, TLD, and User Agent created from different users and devices. Now I want to figure out what apps they used in their devices to make those queries.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's possible in Android.